# Cannon install AWS CodeDeploy Agent on my on-premises Windows machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to install the AWS CodeDeploy Agent on my On-premises Windows machine and here is what I get:

```
aws deploy install --override-config --config-file codedeploy.onpremises.yml
Creating the on-premises instance configuration file... DONE
Installing the AWS CodeDeploy Agent... ERROR
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
Install the AWS CodeDeploy Agent on the on-premises instance by following the instructions in "Configure Existing On-Premises Instances by Using AWS CodeDeploy" in the AWS CodeDeploy User Guide.
```

Notice the ERROR on line 3-4 above:

```
Installing the AWS CodeDeploy Agent... ERROR
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I should note that I could successfully register the machine for CodeDeploy and I can see the registration on AWS console -> CodeDeploy -> On-premises instances

Here are the details of the environment:

- **On-premises instance OS:** Windows Server 2016 Standard Evaluation
- **System Type:** 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- **python --version:** 3.6.5
- **pip --version:** 9.0.3
- **aws --version:** aws-cli/1.16.9 Python/3.6.5 Windows/10 botocore/1.11.9

What possibly can I do to get around the error?

Comment: This error message is common when the wrong version of Python is being used. When I run "aws --version" on my system, Python 2.7.9 is displayed: "aws-cli/1.15.31 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.10.31"

Comment: Did you install the AWS CLI using the Windows installer or PIP? Make sure to install using the Windows Installer if you are using PIP from Python 3.x. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html

Comment: I installed AWS CLI using pip. As you said, I also think Python version mismatch is what's happening here. Based on your suggestion I installed the AWS CLI windows installer for Python 3.x. The issue didn't resolve. I tried removing my existing Python installation and reinstalling the CLI (from .msi). Same result. Then I tried the installer for Python 2.x. This time the error didn't occur, the agent installer was downloaded but the agent service fails to start (no error log). The service stays in 'Starting...' status for a few minutes and then disappears automatically

Comment: I also tried running the command: `codedeploy-agent.msi /quiet /l host-agent-install-log.txt` ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-windows.html)). Same outcome as mentioned above :(

Comment: I appreciate your attention @John. Btw, I am also wondering whether the CodeDeploy agent has any direct dependency on AWS CLI (provided that the machine has already been registered via CLI and the codedeploy yml file is in place)? In other words, Shouldn't the agent be able to do its job even if I uninstall CLI? If so, isn't the agent independent of python? In that case what else could be causing the service failing to start?

Comment: The agent doesn't have a dependency on the CLI. The agent is a Ruby application and uses the AWS SDK. When you try to start the agent, do you see any interesting logs here: `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\CodeDeploy\log\codedeploy-agent-log.txt`?

Comment: Unfortunately no such log file was created. Being out of luck I had to abandon the on-premises venture and moved on to AWS EC2 (linux AMI) where there was no issue installing and running the agent